# how to enter into an infinite loop of expect operations with Tcl?

Tags: iteration, tcl, infinite-loop, expect, telnet

How can I intentionally enter an infinite loop with the telnet server?  (Not literally infinite, but to "cycle" through a sequence with the server.)

whenever presented with a menu of "WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU" or "CITY FORECAST MENU" I'd to enter selection "1" at least for a few iterations.

However, `expect` is somewhat as it stands.

Can I create a sort of "list" of "triggers" so that [whenever a line is read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client) it iterates through a list and selects the first match?

*Currently the `dict` of `cities` only has the single entry, but the notion would be to iterate through that list of, say, five cities.*

automated result (I simply select the connect method of 1):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ tclsh main.tcl 
locations
---------
1   nyc



connect to wunderground with:
-----------------------------
1)  noControlFlow
2)  connect


connection method: 1
connecting with 1
spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
getting weather for nyc
Trying 35.160.169.47...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:

Press Return for menu
or enter 3 letter forecast city code-- 
nyc

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:1

          Not a valid option. Type a number 1 to 12.

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:
                         CITY FORECAST MENU
                ---------------------------------------------------
                1) Print forecast for selected city
                2) Print climatic data for selected city
                3) Display 3-letter city codes for a selected state
                4) Display all 2-letter state codes
                M) Return to main menu
                X) Exit program
                ?) Help
                   Selection:1

          Enter 3-letter city code: nyc
Weather Conditions at 06:51 AM EDT on 11 May 2020 for New York JFK, NY.
Temp(F)    Humidity(%)    Wind(mph)    Pressure(in)    Weather
========================================================================
  49          93%         SSE at 6       29.88      Mostly Cloudy

Forecast for New York, NY
527 am EDT Mon may 11 2020

.Today...Mostly cloudy. A slight chance of showers early, then a
chance of showers. Isolated thunderstorms this afternoon. Highs
in the lower 60s. Southwest winds 5 to 10 mph with gusts up to
20 mph, increasing to west 15 to 20 mph with gusts up to 30 mph
this afternoon. Chance of rain 50 percent. 
.Tonight...Partly cloudy with a slight chance of showers with
isolated thunderstorms in the evening, then mostly clear after
midnight. Lows in the lower 40s. Northwest winds 15 to 20 mph
with gusts up to 30 mph. Chance of rain 20 percent. 
.Tuesday...Sunny. Highs in the upper 50s. Northwest winds 15 to
20 mph with gusts up to 30 mph. 
.Tuesday night...Partly cloudy in the evening, then clearing.
Lows in the lower 40s. Northwest winds 10 to 15 mph. Gusts up to
25 mph in the evening. 
.Wednesday...Sunny. Highs in the lower 60s. West winds 5 to
   Press Return to continue, M to return to menu, X to exit: thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$
```

code:

```
package provide weather  1.0
package require Expect

namespace eval ::wunderground {
}

#works
proc ::wunderground::noControlFlow {city} {
    variable telnet [spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com]
    puts "getting weather for $city"


    expect "Press Return to continue:"
    send "\r"

    expect "Press Return for menu:"
    send "\r"


    #assuming actually a dictionary of cities
    expect "or enter 3 letter forecast city code--"
    send "$city\r"

    expect "WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU"
    send "1\r"

    expect "CITY FORECAST MENU"
    send "1\r"


    expect "Enter 3-letter city code:"
    send "$city\r"

    expect "Press Return to continue, M to return to menu, X to exit:"
    send "M\r"


}
```

main:

```
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/weather

package require weather 1.0
package require locations 1.0



set cities [cities::dictionary]
puts "locations\n---------"
dict for {k v} $cities {puts $k\t$v}



#################


puts "\n\n\nconnect to wunderground with:"
puts "-----------------------------"
puts "1)\tnoControlFlow"
puts "2)\tconnect\n\n"


puts -nonewline "connection method: "
flush stdout
gets stdin prompt
puts "connecting with $prompt"


if {$prompt == 1 } {
   wunderground::noControlFlow "nyc"
} else {
   wunderground::connect "nyc"
}
```

Comment: Don't expect others to try your telnet and people are not interested in what your weather is. Please use a [mcve] to demonstrate your question.

Comment: pardon?  it's a Tcl question which relates to telnet and expect usage.

Comment: So what's the weather package? How can others try your code? And telnet may not be installed by default nowadays.

Comment: Just as your question title says, it's about infinite loops. You can demo your problem by using common tools. For example you can use a shell.

Comment: saying some variant of "while true" is an infinite loop, but doesn't help with expect that I see and so far as I know it's specific to telnet.  I'm not seeing how creating, for example, an infinite loop of adding users in a shell pertains but am intrigued by the notion.